# wrap breaks when using delete or change word type commands

Tags: cursor-motions, wrapping, line-breaks

Using these options

```
set wrap linebreak nolist

set showbreak=~ "adds specified character after wrap

set breakindent "forces word wrap to start at last lines indentation level

set display=lastline "shows as much of last line as possible in wrap mode
```

when editing prose that expands over multiple lines, if you insert text the wrapping will correctly keep adjusting.

If you instead do `cw` or `2cw` or whatever, text no longer wraps on word, but visually appears to be wrapped by character. But this is actually false, because when you hit <kbd>x</kbd> or some similar command, the character deleted is not the one that was under the cursor.

I have to hit `:se wrap` to adjust the text after doing a `2cw` type of command.

Is there a setting I'm missing, or one I'm using that might be causing this bug?

Using just the plain mac osx Terminal.app

Update:

I am able to reproduce this bug after commenting out my whole .vimrc and running only

```
set wrap linebreak nolist
```

So if I `c2w`, and `f,` `;` a few times to get to a comma on the next line, the cursor will highlight with an inaccuracy of the number of characters that should have been wrapped. So if "Perhaps" was cut off at "Perh" the cursor will be on the second "e" in ", deeper", but pressing x will still delete the comma. So it's a visual problem.

It might not be obvious, but this is a case where you insert more than you deleted with the change command. So `cw` "a man" and replace with "something there" or whatever, in order to force the wrapping to need to readjust.

Comment: Worth noting for any would-be helpers that the `breakindent` option is only included in and after patch-7.4.338.

Comment: Could this be a mac specific issue? I tried it in Gvim windows and everything was fine. Can you may be try it on mac vim too ?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows vim 7.4.0 terminal or Gvim. Try starting vim with with `vim -u NONE` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Using vim -u NONE it's the same problem. Once you write past the $ marker, it will lose your place when you go to a comma on the next line after you exit insert mode and move with normal mode (or any character, but for sake of reproducability and understanding).

Comment: what patchlevel?

Comment: version 7.4.488

Comment: It does not occur in MacVim. That's an option, but not really an answer to using the terminal editor. It's possible this bug does not occur in other terminal emulators, though.

Comment: I think you need a newer Vim. I think, patch [576](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/v7.4.576) fixed it

Comment: Thanks, I think that's it. Updating vim seems to be it's own can of worms :/

Comment: actually, updateing vim works pretty well, if you recompile. That is not really hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version of vim was out of date. As Christian Brabandt pointed out, patch 576 repaired this bug.

To update my vim on Mac OSX, I used

`brew update`
`brew upgrade vim`

Without update, brew thought I had the latest version.